# How to add a loop to scrape the next page of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

My code below works but I want it to do the same exact thing but with the next page of the URL variable, this would be done by adding the number 1,2,3 depending on the page.

The code essentially scrapes a website that has the thumnails of various videos, it then returns the link to each video. I want it to do this for each page available

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen




URL = "domain.com/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

endof = soup.find_all('div',class_="th-image")
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
endoflinks = links[8:-8]

index = 0
for a in endoflinks:
    
    index+=1
    
    dwnlink = "domain.com"+ endoflinks[index]

    
    r = requests.get(dwnlink)
    f = open("output.txt", "a")
    print(r.url, file=f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: show website url

Comment: You just need to iterate over a `range(n)` and append the number to the URL string

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get going:

```
URL = "domain.com/"

for i in list(range(0,10)):
    print("domain.com/"+str(i))
    r = requests.get(URL+str(i))
    f = open("output.txt", "a")
    print(r.url, file=f)
    f.close()
```

```
domain.com/0
domain.com/1
domain.com/2
domain.com/3
domain.com/4
domain.com/5
domain.com/6
domain.com/7
domain.com/8
domain.com/9
```